# Apache Beam Getting CSV Files from Pub/Sub JSON

Tags: apache-beam

I have csv files being pushed to Google Storage and a pubsub subscription that notifies me when they arrive. What I'm trying to accomplish is writting a beam program that will grab the JSON data from the pubsub subscription parse out the file location and then read the csv file from GS and then process those. I have a process that will process read the pubsub and then process it into a pcollection. So far I have this:

```
Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);
final String output = options.getOutput();
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<String> input = pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(StaticValueProvider.of("beamsub")));


  PCollection<String> files = input.apply(ParDo.of(new ParseOutGSFiles()));
```

now i need to do something like this:

```
pipeline.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(FILEsFROMEARLIER).withCompressionType(TextIO.CompressionType.GZIP))
```

any ideas or is this not possible...it seems like it should be easy

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually what would be really convenient if it were just one step to read the incoming csv filies right out of the pubsub. I can only find examples of pubsubio just processing raw data and not pulling it out of a file.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bump this old thread, but do you remember how you wrote the ParseOutGSFiles() function?

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to express your read would be by using TextIO.readAll() method, which reads text files from an input PCollection of file names. This method has been introduced within the Beam codebase, but is not currently in a released version. It will be included in the Beam 2.2.0 release and the corresponding Dataflow 2.2.0 release.

Your result code would look something like

```java
Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
    .withValidation().as(Options.class);
final String output = options.getOutput();
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<String> files = pipeline
    .apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription("beamsub"))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new ParseOutGSFiles()));
PCollection<String> contents = files
    .apply(TextIO.readAll().withCompressionType(TextIO.CompressionType.GZIP));
```

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I want! I can't even seem to find a beta of 2.2.0  is there a way to get that functionality? Or a work around you'd suggest?